# Some questions about a prime-generating sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

I came across an amazing prime-generating sequence :

If $$a_1=7\ ,\ a_{n}=a_{n-1}+gcd(n,a_{n-1})$$ for $n\ge 2$

and $$b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$$ for $n\ge 1$,

it is known that the sequence $b_n$ contains only ones and (odd) primes.

However, I have some questions about the sequence $b_n$ :

> Is it known whether $b_n$ is bounded ?
>
> Is it known whether $b_n$ contains every odd prime ?
>
> Is it known whether $b_n$ contains infinite many numbers greater than $1$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Comment: This is Rowland's Formula see this article: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL11/Rowland/rowland21.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2011, in this [article](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v18i2p10/pdf), Chamizo, Raboso and Ruiz-Cabello show that the sequence $b_n$ contains infinitely many distinct primes. So $b_n$ is NOT bounded and it contains INFINITE many numbers greater than 1. I think that the property that $b_n$ contains every odd prime is still a conjecture.

P.S. Take a look also to this recent [preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05041.pdf) by Ruiz-Cabello.

Comment: Thank you for your research!